# Resolve merge conflicts GIT Azure-devops Server Side

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

Is there any way to resolve merge conflicts on the Azure-devops server? The problem I am running into is I am trying to keep my branches isolated to single request/defects. For example, I have Request1 to create a report to show list of purchases and Request2 to show a list of sales. Both will reside in the solution for Accounting. I commit and push and do a pull request. The first one merges into the master fine, but the 2nd gets a conflict because it doesn't have the 1st one in it. Now when this happened in the past I would simply pull the master into my Request2 and do another push/pull request. However, I am now on a project with a gate keeper and it is adding a lot of time to always have this happen. Is there any way to do something like: Resolve merge conflicts section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio from the server? Usually the only conflict is a report in master that is not in branch, but that is a single XML line. I just want to merge the files and keep the missing line and the new line. This way the Gatekeeper can merge the files without all the back and forth.

Comment: Can you tell waht `Gatekeeper` is and what it does?

Comment: Gatekeeper is a guy names Carol who accepts the pull request and merges the branch into the Master branch. The problem is whenever a conflict happens he has no power to fix it himself. All he really needs to do is accept particular lines of codes from the new branch.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you keep your code on Azure Repos or maybe Github?

Comment: they even fixed, as of date submodules conflicts resolution directly on the tool

Answer (score 5):

There is an [extension](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3Dms-devlabs.conflicts-tab%26ssr%3Dfalse%23overview&data=02%7C01%7Cv-lelu%40microsoft.com%7C0e364121025745ffc7e408d7dc31930d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637219977815610750&sdata=xvFoECHMuCtrQppE7F3BhpKrl2H3saJXWPOLqlC8hgA%3D&reserved=0) to resolve Pull Request conflicts on the web. After installed it to your Azure DevOps Server, you could see a Conflicts tab in Pull Request page, then you could resolve conflicts in web site instead of resolve the conflicts in a local clone.

[image]

Note: There is an known issue that the new changes to master branch after the Pull Request creation will not be recognized by Pull Request. You need to abandon the current PR then create a new one. 
For example, there are two PRs in your repo, feature1 to master and feature2 to master. After feature1 merged into master, the existing PR from feature2 to master will not show the feature1’s changes. You need to abandon it and recreate a new PR. And then you could use the Conflict extension to resolve merge conflicts.

[image]

Update:

Pull Request could not get the latest master changes automatically when new changes push to master branch. Instead of abandon and reactivate the PR, there is a “Restart merge” option which could get the latest changes of master.

[image]

Also you could see the master’s last change time in the conflict tab.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am reading everywhere, but was hoping there was a way around it by now. Seems very simply to fix since the logic is already in VS.

Comment: Sorry about that. Pull Request could not get the latest master changes automatically when new changes push to master branch. Instead of abandon and reactivate the PR, there is a “Restart merge” option which could get the latest changes of master.  Check above update